# How to link deployed library to contract in brownie?

Tags: brownie, library

As far as I know, brownie automatically links the library to contract. Is there a way to do this manually?

I have bunch of contracts in different projects where some use library and some don't. So I wan't to link manually to those needs library in the contract.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Brownie docs, if a contract requires a library, Brownie will automatically link to the most recently deployed one. In other words, Brownie will not automatically link to the most recently deployed one if a contract doesn't require a library.

See: https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-contracts.html

Comment: I already know this.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. I'm open to others if there is a way to simplify it.

```
from pathlib import Path
from solcx import compile_files, link_code
from brownie import web3, accounts, Contract


library_addresses = {"Lib1": <Lib1 address>, "Lib2", <Lib2 address>}
remappings = [
   '@openzeppelin=Openzeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.8.0',
   'libraries=contracts/libraries'
]

contract_file = Path("contracts/MyContract.sol")
contract_compiled_sol = compile_files(
    [contract_file],
    import_remappings=remappings,
    output_values=["abi", "bin"],
    solc_version=<solc version (e.g. "0.8.14")>,
    optimize=True,
)

abi = contract_compiled_sol["contracts/MyContract.sol:MyContract"]["abi"]
bin = contract_compiled_sol["contracts/MyContract.sol:MyContract"]["bin"]
nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accounts[0].address)

# Here is the MAGIC!!!
bin = link_code(
    bin,
    {
        f"contracts/libraries/{lib}.sol:{lib}": library_addresses[lib]
        for lib in library_addresses.keys()
    },
)

MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bin) 

tx_data = {
    "from": accounts[0].address,
    "nonce": nonce,
    "gasPrice": int(web3.eth.gas_price * 1.2), # or whatever you want...
    "gas": 3000000, # or whatever makes sense for your contract...
}

tx = MyContract.constructor(
    arg1,
    arg2,
    ...
).buildTransaction(tx_data)

print(web3.eth.estimateGas(tx)) # Can rebuild transaction with gas estimate

signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(
    tx,
    private_key=accounts[0].private_key,
)

tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash, timeout=360)

print(f"\tTransaction: {tx_hash.hex()}")

print(
    f"\tMyContract successfully deployed to {receipt.contractAddress}"
)

# Now you can interact with your new contract :)
myContract = Contract.from_abi(
    "MyContract",
    receipt.contractAddress,
    abi,
)
```

Please let me know if there was anything I missed. Also please note, I added in the Openzeppelin remapping because it's a common library remapping added to configurations. So more of an additional help for anyone.